# some question about singularity and poles?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $p(z)$ be a non-zero polynomial in complex variable $z$. Let
$f(z) = p(z)e^\frac{1}{z}$ for $z \in \mathbb{C}\setminus  \{0\}$

Then,choose the coorect option

a.$ f$ has a removable singularity at $z = 0$

b. $f$ has a pole at $z = 0$ with residue equal to $0.$

c. $f$ has an essential singularity at $z = 0.$

d. $f$ has a pole at $z = 0$ with residue equal to $1$.

i thinks  option b) will correct because $\lim_{z\rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{z}= \infty  $   as $f(z) = \infty  $

is it correct/not correct  ?

thanks u, Any hints/solution

Comment: If you want to show that (b) is correct -which I am not saying nor denying it is- why don't you check the condition for having a pole there? Recall that a (meromorphic) function $f$ has a pole of order $n$ at $z = a$ if the limit $\lim_{z \rightarrow a} (z-a)^nf(z)$ exists and is non-zero. Also, you may regard that, since $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed, you may write $p(z)$ as the product $p(z) = c \cdot \prod_{i} (z - z_i)^{m_i}$, where the $z_i$ are (the) roots of $p$ of multiplicity $m_i$ and $c$ is the leading coefficient of $p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's c. We have no idea as far as the residue is concerned, because it depends on the unknown polynomial $p(z)$. The singularity can't be eliminated by any polynomials.

Comment: im not getting @Miles   can u elaborate more

Comment: @Miles is right, the answer being (c). Another hint: instead of forcibly computing the limit, try computing the limit of $\log f(z)$. This shall split in two parts, one of which presents an obvious problem.

Comment: @Messififa, assume $p(z)=z^nq(z), \ n>=0$ with $q(z)$ doesn't have zero or pole at 0. The Laurent series of $f(z)=q(z)\left(z^n+\frac12z^{n-1}+...+\frac1{n!}+\frac1{(n+1)!}z^{-1}+...\right)$. The residue is determined by the coefficient of the term $z^{-1},\ q(0)\frac1{(n+1)!}$. If $n<0$, the situation is a little simpler, and I guess you can figure it out.

Comment: By the way, why the preview of the edit tool is missing? I had to edit many times to make the MathJax right.

Comment: @MilesZhou thanks u